# How to join multiple Kafka topics in StreamSets Data Collector?

Tags: apache-kafka, stream-processing, streamsets

I have a use case where I have to "join" multiple Kafka topics based on some criteria in StreamSets Data Collector. I wonder if there is some commonly adopted idiom that could solve such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

StreamSets Data Collector is really not the right tool for this sort of job, since a Data Collector pipeline can have only one origin.

You should look at [StreamSets Transformer](https://streamsets.com/products/transformer/), which is built on Spark specifically to be able to join multiple streams of data and perform similar tasks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Kafka Multitopic Consumer [1](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Origins/KafkaMultiConsumer.html) then the Stream Selector Processor [2](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/StreamSelector.html?hl=stream%2Cselector) to route to trash or processing based on you criteria?